# Parse Input and Determine Type of Data

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to take input from user and then want to find is it Integer, float or something else. Till now I am using Scanner class for that. Like `Scanner scan1=new Scanner(System.in);
     String st= scan1.next();` and then I am trying to parse that input (st) in int and float respectively. But with this approach I am not able to satisfy the "else" condition. i.e. when input is neither string, int nor float. 
Below is the code I tried :-

```
public String checkInput() {
    String statement = "This input is of type ";
    String inputType;

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String st = scan1.next();
    scan1.close();
    inputType = st.getClass().getSimpleName();
    try {
        Float numFloat = Float.parseFloat(st);
        inputType = numFloat.getClass().getSimpleName();

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    }
    try {
        Integer numInt = Integer.parseInt(st);
        inputType = numInt.getClass().getSimpleName();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    }

    return statement + inputType;
}
```

here I am not able to decide how should I place else condition to check the input is neither string,float nor integer.

Comment: It would probably be good enough to just change your third line to `String inputType = "UNKNOWN";` - if both your `try` blocks fail you'll return `"This input is of type UNKNOWN"`.

Comment: @dimo414 but considering fifth line, if input would not be float or Integer, it will always return inputType as string.

Comment: @Vic can you provide any help or link, how could I use it.

Comment: @Er.NavedAli then use `"String"` instead, or whatever text you'd like :) it depends on what you want the behavior to be - if you expect the inputs to be a `float` or a `int` then anything else is "unknown", if strings are an expected possibility then they're not unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would restructure your code. I'll explain the changes below:

```
private static final String STATEMENT = "This input is of type ";

public static String checkInput(Scanner scanner) {
  if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
    return STATEMENT + Float.class.getSimpleName();
  else if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    return STATEMENT + Integer.class.getSimpleName();
  }
  return STATEMENT + "UNKNOWN";
}
```

- First, we pulled `statement` out into a [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)), since it's not being changed.
- Second, we pass the `Scanner` in as a parameter, rather than constructing a new one. There are a number of reasons to prefer this, but the principle one is that you should avoid creating multiple `Scanner` instances reading from `System.in` - generally you'll create such a `Scanner` in your `main()` method and pass it off to the methods and classes that need to use it.
- Next, rather than reading from the scanner directly, we use the `has*()` methods to inspect the scanner's state without advancing it. This changes the semantics of `checkInput()`, because when it returns the input being inspected is still in the scanner, but that's more consistent with a method named `check...()` - it should inspect, not change state. Because your implementation calls `.next()` you lose the actual provided input, which is presumably undesirable.
- Finally, we `return` from inside each block, rather than setting a temporary `inputType` variable and returning it at the end.

Your `main()` method might now look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // using try-with-resources so we don't have to call .close()
  try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println(checkInput(scanner));
    String input = scanner.next(); // this actually advances the scanner
    System.out.println("You input: " + input);
  }
}
```

---

Taking it further, you might prefer to have `checkInput()` return a `Class<?>` rather than a `String`, and then construct your statement separately. This would allow you to handle the inputs differently. For example:

```
public static Class<?> inputType(Scanner scanner) {
  if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
    return Float.class;
  else if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    return Integer.class;
  }
  // add other types as needed
  return String.class;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    Class<?> inputType = inputType(scanner);
    String input = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("You input: " + input);
    if (inputType.equals(Integer.class)) {
      System.out.prinln("That's a valid integer!");
    }
  }
}
```

---

**All that said**, we're very much reinventing the wheel here. The "right" way to use `Scanner` is to use the typed methods directly - e.g.:

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  int value = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

This avoids needing to do any manual type checking or similar busywork - just let `Scanner` do the validation for you.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation :)